# Designing an asynchronous task library for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

The ASP.NET runtime is meant for short work loads that can be run in parallel. I need to be able to schedule periodic events and background tasks that may or may not run for much longer periods.

Given the above I have the following problems to deal with:

- The AppDomain can shutdown due to changes (Web.config, bin, App_Code, etc.)
- IIS recycles the AppPool on a regular basis (daily)
- IIS itself might restart, or for that matter the server might crash

I'm not convinced that running this code inside ASP.NET is not the right thing to do, becuase it would allow for a simpler programming model. But doing so would require that an external service periodically makes requests to the app so that the application is keept running and that all background tasks are programmed with utter most care. They will have to be able to pause and resume thier work, in the event of an unexpected error.

My current line of thinking goes something like this:

If all jobs are registered in the database, it should be possible to use the database as a bookkeeping mechanism. In the case of an error, the database would contain all state necessary to resume the operation at the next opportunity given.

I'd really appriecate some feedback/advice, on this matter. I've been considering running a windows service and using some RPC solution as well, but it doesn't have the same appeal to me. And I'd instead have a lot of deployment issues and sycnhronizing tasks and code cross several applications. Due to my business needs this is less than optimial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark since I don't know what database you use, but I'd recommend you to consider [dialog timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) and [activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx). Assuming that *most* of the jobs have to do some data manipulation, and is likely that *all* have to do *only* data manipulation, leveraging activation and timers give an extremely reliable job scheduling solution, entirely embedded in the database (no need for an external process/service, not dependencies outside the database bounds like msdb), and is a solution that ensures scheduled jobs can survive restarts, failover events and even disaster recovery restores. Simply put, once a job is scheduled it will run even if the database is restored one week later on a different machine.

Have a look at [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) for a related example.

And if this is too radical, at least have a look at [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) since storing the scheduled items in the database often falls under the 'pending queue' case.

Comment: +1 for the link to the article on Asynchronous procedure execution.

Comment: That is awesome, unfortunately not all background tasks can be written in just T-SQL, many of them probably could, but right now, we have limited debugging support for T-SQL, as well as, things that have to be in C# code, like sending e-mails. Also, some of these transformations that we do, really look awkward in SQL and are often easier for us to maintain using C# code. About tables as queues, I've done something similar in the past, but haven't seen these variations before, thanks for the links.

Comment: Activation can launch CLR procedures as well, and there is also an external activator than can launch ordinary processes (.exe): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/11/21/announcing-service-broker-external-activator.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you have a look at Quartz.Net. It is open source and it will give you some ideas.

Comment: More than give you some ideas, it will pretty much do exactly what you want.

Comment: Except it fails to answer my biggest concern about the feasibility of using ASP.NET as a hosting environment for asynchronous tasks. Quartz, how awesome it might be, won't help here.

Comment: 5 years later and here I am still looking for an asp.net friendly and reliable background job scheduler with async job execution

Answer (score 2):

Using the database as a state-keeping mechanism is a completely valid idea. How complex it will be depends on how far you want to take it. In many cases you will ended up pairing your database logic with a Windows service to achieve the desired result.

FWIW, it is typically not a good practice to manually use the thread pool inside an ASP.Net application, though (contrary to what you may read) it actually works quite nicely other than the huge caveat that you can't **guarantee** it will work.

So if you needed a background thread that examined the state of some object every 30 seconds and you didn't care if it fired every 30 seconds or 29 seconds or 2 minutes (such as in a long app pool recycle), an ASP.Net-spawned thread is a quick and very dirty solution.

Asynchronously fired callbacks (such as on the ASP.Net Cache object) can also perform a sort of "behind the scenes" role.

I have faced similar challenges and ultimately opted for a Windows service that uses a combination of building blocks for maximum flexibility.  Namely, I use:

1) WCF with implementation-specific types OR

2) Types that are meant to transport and manage objects that wrap a job OR

3) Completely generic, serializable objects contained in a custom wrapper.  Since they are just a binary payload, this allows any object to be passed to the service. Once in the service, the wrapper defines what should happen to the object (e.g. invoke a method, gather a result, and optionally make that result available for return).

Ultimately, the web site is responsible for querying the service about its state. This querying can be as simple as polling or can use asynchronous callbacks with WCF (though I believe this also uses some sort of polling behind the scenes).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm considering serializing types (sending the IL code) for execution in a remote environment. If I go with the Windows service approach, then I'll need a really flexible remoting or remote invocation mechanism, maybe WCF could facilitate this but there's still gonna be lots of small tasks that will only exist in certain code bases and these need to somehow work with the service.

Comment: I found the DataContract restrictions using WCF to be hard to deal with when you need to send numerous types of objects to a service for remote execution. I got around this by declaring a few wrapper objects capable of transporting my object trees (as byte arrays) and simple instructions on how to use those objects. Then WCF only needs to be aware of the interfaces of those wrapper objects, and one of the big barriers is removed (IMO). When you say "only exist in certain codebases", do you mean that the execution host would not be able to reference those types?

Comment: Obviously the execution host has to be able to references those types, but it's never a fixed set of things that has to be done. This varies a lot. Subtle but differences exist. I don't see my self creating a host of services that will be run on behalf of some other application.

Answer (score 1):

I tell you what I have do.

I have create a class called **Atzenta** that have a timer (1-2 second trigger).
I have also create a table on my temporary database that keep the jobs. The table knows the jobID, other parameters, priority, job status, messages.

I can add, or delete a job on this class. When there is no action to be done the timer is stop. When I add a job, then the timer starts again. (the timer is a thread by him self that can do parallel work). I use the System.Timers [and not other timers for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

The jobs can have different priority.

Now let say that I place a job on this table using the **Atzenta** class. The next time that the timer is trigger is check the query on this table and find the first available job and just run it. No other jobs run until this one is end.

Every synchronize and flags are done from the table. In the table I have flags for every job that show if its |wait to run|request to run|run|pause|finish|killed|

All jobs are all ready known functions or class (eg the creation of statistics).

For stop and start, I use the global.asax and the Application_Start, Application_End to start and pause the object that keep the tasks. For example when I do a job, and I get the Application_End ether I wait to finish and then stop the app, ether I stop the action, notify the table, and start again on application_start.

So I say, **Atzenta.RunTheJob(Jobs.StatisticUpdate, ProductID)**; and then I add this job on table, open the timer, and then on trigger this job is run and I update the statistics for the given product id.

I use a table on a database to synchronize many pools that run the same web app and in fact its work that way. With a common table the synchronize of the jobs is easy and you avoid 2 pools to run the same job at the same time.

On my back office I have a simple table view to see the status of all jobs.

Comment: I like this, have you had any problems related to the app crashing or being interrupted in unexpected ways?

Comment: @John No I do not have any special problems. I do not shut-down the web service but I open the app_offline.htm when I make update then I wait to see on the my log that all application have be done - so I do not force them to stop. Also its not crashing - if it is I see it on log and make try/catch block and so on. If process on the table have been crash for any reason I understand it by the fact that the state is on run, but I am not running anything at this time. Its one more simple flag saved on database that I run something.

Comment: @John one of the process is a custom index of my text on database. The first day it was run for more than 28h to complete with out any problems. Later I fix a way that I can flag it and pause this indexer.