# Background thread 'job-queue' in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

Context: I have a photo-uploading website set up. I need to perform operations on these uploads every time a user uploads a photo.

With help from other users here on SO, I came to the conclusion, that I needed a background thread that accepted these "processing jobs", so I could return response to the user quickly, and let the background thread work on these background jobs.

I'm sort of "set" on a threading solution as opposed to a service for instance, as it's not possible for me to set up a service on the webserver. I've read some things on message queues, and background threads, but I'm really in need of is some practical pointers as to how I should proceed.

Also - are there any things I should be aware of? Off the top of my head, I'm thinking about the number of threads, and possibly hitting a snag with the IIS or server if too many threads are running? That's why I'm thinking it should be a single background thread per user, and not a thread per job, as there could be MANY photos uploaded at once. So a single thread per user that takes care of the jobs in a 'queue' like fashion. Am I way off base?

Comment: I'm just gonna say it, if you wanna do asynchronous work within a IIS process your gonna run into trouble. A service is what you should be using because your web server is not a silver bullet. It's fundamentally wrong to think that your web server is a place for background tasks.

Comment: I would rather go the service route myself, but as this is not possible, I have no choice but to look into threading.

Comment: @Dynde - You know threading is not a choice it's a fact of life, you gonna do threading either way. May I ask why this is not possible? Why is it that you can't use a Windows service with your web application?

Comment: Cause it's not my server :) It's a simple web-host.

Comment: Have you tried talking to them and see if you can't get access to a VM or something like that? I doesn't cost a fortune to rent a VM.

Comment: Access is out of the question, as otherwise it would be exactly like you say - a rented VM :) And I know it doesn't cost a fortune. But a webhost for one euro a month is hard to beat :) As of right now, it's not viable for me to rent a VM though, and is outside the scope of the question - otherwise, I wouldn't even think twice about a VM and consequently a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run as many threads as you like, but you'll run the risk of spending more time on context switching that actual crunching. If you need good CPU performance you should use no more than 1 thread per CPU core. The PLINQ stuff has this exact strategy. If you tell PLINQ to run a query it will execute in parallel the equivalent of the number of CPU cores available on your system.

If you're gonna implement queue, you should be thinking of a FIFO queue, users put their work in a bunch of threads or servers pull work from this queue and does the work.

i.e. you can use a SQL Server database to synchronize work cross many machines using a FIFO queue in the database (this is just a simple table that you pull work from). It will scale pretty well and it's also more robust because work can be resumed if it crashes or timeouts.

You should read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869784/designing-an-asynchronous-task-library-for-asp-net) i posted about this a while back. Remus Rusanu posted some intresting links on the topic that discusses the use of a database to orchestrate work loads.